# MPI - Use multiple threads to listen for incoming messages

Tags: c++11, mpi, openmpi

I am working on a project that uses MPI routines and multiple threads for sending and receiving messages. I would like each receiving thread to focus on a different incoming message instead of having two or more trying to receive the same one. Is there a way to achieve this?

I don't know if this helps but I am currently using Iprobe() to check for incoming messages and Irecv() with Test() to check if the thread has received the whole message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 3 of the standard, MPI allows for the removal of matched messages from the message queue so that they are no longer visible to subsequent probes/receives. This is done using the so-called *matched probes*. Just replace `MPI_Iprobe` with `MPI_Improbe`, which is the non-blocking matched probe operation:

```
int flag;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Message msg;

MPI_Improbe(source, tag, comm, &flag, &msg, &status);
```

Once `MPI_Improbe` returns 1 in `flag`, a message matching `(source, tag, comm)` has arrived. A handle to the message is stored into `msg` and the message is removed from the queue. Subsequent probes or receives with a matching (source, tag, comm) triplet - by the same thread or in another - won't see the same message again and therefore won't interfere with its reception by the thread that matched it originally.

To receive a matched message, use `MPI_Imrecv` (or the blocking `MPI_Mrecv`):

```
MPI_Request req;
MPI_Imrecv(buffer, count, dtype, &msg, &req);
do
{
   ...
   MPI_Test(&req, &flag, &status);
}
while (!flag);
```

Versions of MPI before 3.0 do not provide similar functionality. But, if I understand you correctly, you only need to guarantee that no matching probe will be posted before `MPI_Irecv` has had the opportunity to remove the message from the queue (which is what matched probe+receive is meant to prevent). If you are probing in a master thread and then dispatching the messages to different threads, then you could use a semaphore to delay the execution of the next probe by the main thread until after the worker has issued `MPI_Irecv`. If you have multiple threads doing probe+receive, then you may simply issue the `MPI_Irecv` call in the same critical section (or whatever synchronisation primitive you use to achieve the serialisation of the MPI calls as required by `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`) as `MPI_Iprobe` once the probe turns out successful:

```
// Worker thread
CRITICAL(mpi)
{
  MPI_Iprobe(source, tag, comm, &flag, &status);
  if (flag)
    MPI_Irecv(buffer, count, dtype, status.MPI_SOURCE, status.MPI_TAG, comm, &req);
}
```

Replace the `CRITICAL(name) { ... }` notation with whatever primitives your programming environment provides.

Comment: I apologise because I think I didn't make my question very clear. The sending threads should not be aware of the number of receiving threads or theirs IDs on the receiving process. The rank of the receiving process should be enough. What I really want is to know if there is a way for receiving processes to detect whether one of them has started receiving an incoming message (which gives it a "busy" state) so that the rest (which are in a "free" state) can deal with the rest of the incoming messages.

Comment: By the way I am using the MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED support level because I read on the OpenMPI documentation that MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE hasn't been thoroughly tested but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see, then you should actually use MPI-3 non-blocking matched probes (`MPI_Improbe`) in combination with (non-blocking) matched receives (`MPI_(I)mrecv`). Matched operations hide the message from the message queue once it has been matched. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, that must be exactly what I was looking for. Yes, please update your answer so I can accept it. One more thing: I can use matched operations but you said they were in MPI-3 and I would like to provide code that works with previous versions as well. Do you know of any ways of achieving that using pre-MPI3 routines?

Comment: @GeorgeG, there you go, I've replaced the entire answer with what you probably need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it's not the matter how you receive messages but how you send them. As you can see below `MPI_Send` function has `destination` parameter which defines to which thread this message will be sent.

```
MPI_Send(
    void* data,
    int count,
    MPI_Datatype datatype,
    int destination,
    int tag,
    MPI_Comm communicator)
```

So if you wan to make certain threads receive certain messages you have to send this messages only to that thread.

Comment: But the destination is the rank of the MPI process to receive the message, not the thread in that process, right?

Comment: As far as remember MPI processes runs on single thread each if it's possible. So in dual core environment you will have up two processes on separate threads. Problem starts when you have more processes than treads and then some of them will be sharing threads among each others.